# Word for killing half a people or group?

Tags: single-word-requests

Its usually referred to by an euphemism, but is there a formal word like an equivalent of "decimation"?

Comment: **Thanossification**

Comment: Or, more seriously, instead of "the population was decimated", try, simply, "the population was **halved**"

Comment: You can just replace _deci_ with _duo_, for _duomation_

Comment: @Zack wouldn't that make it "doubled"?  deci = 1/10, duo = 2.  Maybe *semimate*.  :-)

Comment: @Hellion: Except _seminate_ sounds like _inseminate_, which brings on all sorts of wrong connotations. :)  Maybe _semicide_...

Comment: @Hellion please make it an answer

Comment: @JesvinJose it's not a recognized word, and its meaning is not readily deducible based on its elements, so I don't actually recommend that you use it.

Answer (score 1):

No current word is as precise about killing half a population as *decimation* or *tithing* are about killing a tenth of a population.

However, with some context, **halve** works. [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/halve):

> Reduce or be reduced by half.

For contextually appropriate uses, look no further than explanations of what Thanos did in Avengers: Infinity War:

> Thanos does not care if a population is already at equilibrium or is even using less resources than they produce. His stated goal is "to wipe out half the universe"(Gamora- Infinity War), not "set the universes population to half of the universes population as of time X". He would not care that the population has been **[halved](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/195055/why-did-thanos-slaughter-half-of-this-population-at-the-start-of-avengers-infin/195059#195059)**, if he wasn't the one responsible.
>
> Thanos **[halving](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/195261/thanos-halving-the-universes-population-makes-no-sense-regarding-population-gro)** the universe's population makes no sense regarding population growth